# Datatype of tabs.url in Chrome Extension with Firebase throws error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to write a tab url I get from a chrome extension to the Firebase database. However, FB throws an error, namely:

> extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in response to tabs.query: Error: Firebase.update failed: First argument contains an invalid key ([object MouseEvent]) in path /user-posts/[object MouseEvent]/-KM8uJZHiNsgtQbNh13I. Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

The corresponding code in my **popup.js**:

```
  function writeNewPost(uid) {

  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
    var urlvar = tabs[0].url;

  var postData = {
    uid: uid,
    url: urlvar
  };

  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;

  var updates = {};
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);


 });

};
```

So does it complain because the url contains forbidden characters? It must be somehow possible to convert it in order to then write it to the database.

The function gets called through this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', writeNewPost);
 });
```

The uid comes from the **background.js,** where the login is handled.

```
var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
```

And it does return something.
What troubles me is that this same line in my **popup.js** returns null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the offending part is `uid` and has nothing to do with `chrome.tabs` API call - it comes from the outside <del>(that you do not show)</del>.

It looks like you set `writeNewPost` as a handler for a mouse click - so it's getting passed a `MouseEvent` event object as its first parameter. That's where your error is.

---

It probably makes most sense to concentrate all your Firebase operations in the background page context - so instead of trying to call it directly, [pass a Message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background to perform the operation for you - because otherwise you have 2 instances of Firebase API and you need to do auth in *both*.

Comment: I see. So you are suggesting an alternative to the mouse click event? I'm having trouble finding a different way to call this. Code is updated above.

Comment: Where does the `uid` come from? The problem is that it's defined as the argument of the function. It's fine to call the function as a handler (or from a handler), but `uid` has to come from _somewhere_.

Comment: It comes from the background.js, but I just noticed it is null in the popup.js (where the writenewpost function is located).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the uid is null during firebase.initializeApp() in the beginning of my popup.js. Calling firebase.auth().currentUser.uid in the function above returns the actual uid:

```
  function writeNewPost() {

  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
    var urlvar = tabs[0].url;

    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid; //This

  var postData = {
    uid: uid,
    url: urlvar
  };

  var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('posts').push().key;

  var updates = {};
  updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData;
  updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData;

  return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);


 });

};
```